# eslint-plugin-angular TypeError: Cannot read property 'johnpapa' of undefined

Tags: eslint

I've installed `eslint-plugin-angular` globally.

eg:

`npm install -g eslint
npm install -g eslint-plugin-angular`

According to http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring using .json files is an option.

Here's my `.eslintrc.json` file.

`json
{
    "env" : {
        "browser": true,
        "jquery": true
    },
    "plugins": [
        "angular"
    ],
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:angular/johnpapa"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "semi": ["error", "always"]
    }
}`

The main error I'm running into is this:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'johnpapa' of undefined`

Looking at the documentation: https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular#usage-without-shareable-config

I can't see why `plugin:angular/johnpapa` wouldn't work.  Do you have to use .yml?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the changed *.eslintrc.json* below.

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "angular": true,
    "require": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:angular/johnpapa"
  ],
  "rules": { /* rules here */ }
}
```